# Take symmetrical pairs, of different numbers from list

Tags: haskell

I have a list like this:

```
[(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(3,2),(3,4),(3,6),(4,3),(4,5),(4,7),(5,2),(5,4),(5,6),(6,3),(6,5),(6,7),(7,2),(7,4),(7,6)]
```

The digits are from [2..7]. I want to take a set where there are any symmetrical pairs. e.g. [(1,2),(2,1)], but those two numbers aren't used again in the set. An example would be:

```
[(3,6),(6,3),(2,5),(5,2),(4,7),(7,4)]
```

I wanted to first put symmetric pairs together as I thought it might be easier to work with so i created this function, which actually creates the pairs and puts them in another list

```
g xs = [ (y,x):(x,y):[] | (x,y) <- xs ]
```

with which the list turns to this:

```
[[(3,2),(2,3)],[(5,2),(2,5)],[(7,2),(2,7)],[(2,3),(3,2)],[(4,3),(3,4)],[(6,3),(3,6)],[(3,4),(4,3)],[(5,4),(4,5)],[(7,4),(4,7)],[(2,5),(5,2)],[(4,5),(5,4)],[(6,5),(5,6)],[(3,6),(6,3)],[(5,6),(6,5)],[(7,6),(6,7)],[(2,7),(7,2)],[(4,7),(7,4)],[(6,7),(7,6)]]
```

Then from here I was hoping to somehow remove duplicates.

I made a function that will look at all of the fst elements of all of the pairs:

```
flatList xss = [ x | xs <- xss, (x,y) <- xs ]
```

to use with another function to remove the duplicates.

```
h (x:xs) | (fst (head x)) `elem` (flatList xs) = h xs
         | otherwise = (head x):(last x):(h xs)
```

which gives me the list

```
[(3,6),(6,3),(5,6),(6,5),(2,7),(7,2),(4,7),(7,4),(6,7),(7,6)]
```

which has duplicate numbers. That function only takes into account the first element of the first pair in the list of lists,the problem is when I also take into account the first element of the second pair (or the second element of the first pair):

```
h (x:xs) | (fst (head x)) `elem` (flatList xs) || (fst (last x)) `elem` (flatList xs) = h xs
         | otherwise = (head x):(last x):(h xs)
```

I only get these two pairs:

[(6,7),(7,6)]

I see that the problem is that this method of deleting duplicates grabs the last repeated element, and would work with a list of digits, but not a list of pairs, as it misses pairs it needs to take.

Is there another way to solve this, or an alteration I could make?

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you aim to do. For example both `6` and `3` are used in the set, but `(3,6), (6,3)` is still part of the expected result?

Comment: Yes, the pair should be in the result, but the other pairs shouldn't use those numbers

Comment: but then it is not clear why `(2,3)` and `(3,2)` is not in the result, and `(3,6),(6,3)` is. Since `(2,3)` is in the original list before `(3,6)`.

Comment: I don't think it would matter how it was put together, there's not just one possible answer, I was just giving one example, but yes, logically it would probably first take the (2,3), it would include (3,2), and the rest of the set would be different.

Comment: In the end I need a set like I've described, symmetric pairs where the numbers aren't used again, taken from a list, e.g. 2..7, that satisfy some predicate. In this case, the original list satisfies the predicate, odd (x + y) where x and y come from the pairs (x,y). Eventually I'll need to know if all the numbers from the list are used as well.

Comment: See also the [Wikipedia page on maximum cardinality matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching).

Answer (score 0):

It probably makes more sense to use a 2-tuple of 2-tuples in your list comprehension, since that makes it more easy to do pattern matching, and thus "by contract" enforces the fact that there are two items. We thus can construct 2-tuples that contain the 2-tuples with:

```
g :: Eq a => [(a, a)] -> [((a, a), (a, a))]
g xs = [ (t, s) | (t@(x,y):ts) <- tails xs, let s = (y, x), elem s ts ]
```

Here the `elem s ts` checks if the "swapped" 2-tuple occurs in the rest of the list.

Then we still need to filter the elements. We can make use of a function that uses an accumulator for the thus far obtained items:

```
h :: Eq a => [((a, a), (a, a))] -> [(a, a)]
h = go []
    where go _ [] = []
          go seen ((t@(x, y), s):xs)
              | notElem x seen && notElem y seen = t : s : go (x:y:seen) xs
              | otherwise = go seen xs
```

For the given sample input, we thus get:

```
Prelude Data.List> (h . g) [(2,3),(2,5),(2,7),(3,2),(3,4),(3,6),(4,3),(4,5),(4,7),(5,2),(5,4),(5,6),(6,3),(6,5),(6,7),(7,2),(7,4),(7,6)]
[(2,3),(3,2),(4,5),(5,4),(6,7),(7,6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading a few times your question, I got an elegant solution to your problem. Thinking that if you have a list of pairs without any repeated number, you can get the list of swapped pairs easily, solving your problem. So your problem can be reduce to *given a list, get the list of all pairs using each number just one*.

For a given list, there are many solutions to this, ex: for `[1,2,3,4]` valid solutions are: `[(2,4),(4,2),(1,3),(3,1)]` and `[(2,3),(3,2),(1,4),(4,1)]`, etc... The approach here is:

- take a permutation if the original list (say `[1,4,3,2]`)
- pick one element for each half and pair them together (for simplicity, you can pick consecutive elements too)
- for each pair, create a the swapped pair and put all together

By doing so you end up with a list of non repeating numbers of pairs and its symmetric. More over, looping around all permutaitons, you can get all the solutions to your problem.

```
import Data.List (permutations, splitAt)
import Data.Tuple (swap)

-- This function splits a list by the half of the length
splitHalf :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitHalf xs = splitAt (length xs `quot` 2) xs

-- This zip a pair of list into a list of pairs 
zipHalfs :: ([a], [a]) -> [(a,a)]
zipHalfs (xs, ys) = zip xs ys

-- Given a list of tuples, creates a larger list with all tuples and all swapped tuples
makeSymetrics :: [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
makeSymetrics xs = foldr (\t l -> t:(swap t):l) [] xs

-- This chain all of the above. 
-- Take all permutations of xs >>> for each permutations >>> split it in two >>> zip the result >>> make swapped pairs
getPairs :: [a] -> [[(a,a)]]
getPairs xs =  map (makeSymetrics . zipHalfs . splitHalf) $ permutations xs
```

```
>>> getPairs [1,2,3,4]
[[(1,3),(3,1),(2,4),(4,2)],[(2,3),(3,2),(1,4),(4,1)] ....
```